Electron Forge does not pass specific `arch` for universal Mac builds
We are using ffmpeg-static in our Electron app, and creating a universal mac build via electron-forge and under the hood electron/universal.  But only the arm64 ffmpeg binary exists in the final app. I have confirmed that the ffmpeg-static module can be rebuilt manually with an arch param as arm64 or x86 (npm rebuild --arch=x64 -f ffmpeg-static, then confirmed with file node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg) and the correct binary is created/downloaded. But when running the universal build, only os.arch() seems to be respected, which in this case is which is an M1 machine.
It seems electron-forge isn't passing the correct arch to dependencies.  If there were hooks in the universal build process, or some env vars set, I could manually rebuild this one ffmpeg module according to an arch. For example ffmpeg-static does read process.env.npm_config_arch, so if I were able to set that in between the x64 and arm64 builds (or electron/universal did), the module would build the correct ffmpeg binary.
I have attempted using hooks in electron-forge to try and switch based on arch, but that value is always universal.  Also, building the app on separate Intel and M1 machines produces the appropriate ffmpeg binary.
How can ffmpeg-static in our case receive the correct arch?

The issue you mention with ffmpeg-static in an Electron universal build stems from the fact that electron-forge and electron/universal don't automatically rebuild or configure native modules like ffmpeg-static for each architecture when creating a universal binary. The universal build combines x86_64 and arm64 binaries into a single executable, but it seems that your native module (ffmpeg-static) is only being built for one architecture (likely the architecture of the build machine).
To ensure that ffmpeg-static contains binaries for both architectures, you need to perform a few steps to manually handle the architecture-specific builds and integrate them into your universal build process.
1. Rebuild ffmpeg-static for Each Architecture
You need to rebuild ffmpeg-static for both architectures (x86_64 and arm64). You can automate this using npm scripts or manually run the rebuild commands.
For x86_64:
npm rebuild ffmpeg-static --arch=x64

For arm64:
npm rebuild ffmpeg-static --arch=arm64

2. Create a Script to Manage Binaries
You need a script to manage the ffmpeg-static binaries for both architectures. Create a script to handle this, something to the tune of:
#!/bin/bash

# Define paths for architecture-specific binaries
ARCHS=("x64" "arm64")
BUILD_DIR="node_modules/ffmpeg-static"

for ARCH in "${ARCHS[@]}"; do
  npm rebuild ffmpeg-static --arch=$ARCH
done

# Ensure both binaries are copied or merged correctly into the final build directory
# Assuming a typical build setup, you may need to copy binaries to a specific location

# Example for copying binaries to a specific directory
mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}/x64
mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}/arm64
cp -r node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg ${BUILD_DIR}/x64/ffmpeg
cp -r node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg ${BUILD_DIR}/arm64/ffmpeg

3. Modify the package.json Scripts
Ensure that your package.json has a script to run the above shell script before building your Electron app. Something like:
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "./path-to-your-script.sh",
  "build": "electron-forge make"
}

4. Handle Universal Binary Creation
When you run the universal build, ensure that both architecture-specific binaries are properly included in the final application bundle. You may need to verify the resulting bundle to ensure it contains both versions of the ffmpeg binary.
Summary
The key steps are rebuilding ffmpeg-static for both architectures, managing these binaries, and ensuring that the universal build process includes both binaries. You may need to experiment with copying and managing binaries, but the essential approach is to ensure that your Electron app's packaging process includes the correct binaries for both architectures.
